# Absolute Row Reference

Tags: excel

I'm attempting to create a formula that will always reference data in cells on row 5.

Current Formula `=(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),SUM(ROW()-COUNT(ROW())+5),MOD(COLUMN()+1,-4)))`

This is giving me the relative active cell address in the worksheet

```
=(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))
```

This is giving me the column offset. My data repeats in sets of 4 so the formula takes the current column adds one then divides by four. The remainder is the column offset I will use.

```
MOD(COLUMN()+1,-4)))
```

The section I'm having a problem on is the row reference for the formula. The data i need is always in row 5 so i was attempting to use the code below to find the current row subtract the row count and add five to land in row five. However the code is evaluating to 1 so either I'm overlooking something or this will not work.

Any help would be great.

```
SUM(ROW()-COUNT(ROW())+5)
```

Example.
if the active cell is C17 then I want to subtract 17 and add 5 to end up on row C5. I using this method as the active cell could be any cell in the worksheet.

Comment: I find your question hard to understand. Maybe you could try `=INDEX(5:5, 0, COLUMN())`?

Comment: similar as Jerry suggets, you can use this one `=INDEX(5:5, 0, CELL("col"))` where `CELL("col")` returns column of _avtive cell_.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jerry but a version that can be dragged up or down and still refer to Row5:

```
=INDEX($5:$5, 0, COLUMN())
```